# Using the word "quota" in plural and singular

Tags: grammatical-number

If I need to use the word "quota" in both the plural and the singular, what is the correct form?

Is it "several quota" and "one quotum" or "several quotas" and "one quota"?

Comment: what does your favorite dictionary say?

Comment: Also, have a look at : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quota%2Cquotum%2C+quotas&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquota%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquotum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquotas%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @medica Neither the concise OED (app) nor the online Merriam-Webster list "quotum". Wiktionary gives it as a plural of "quota", but the definition leaves me wondering if it's what I'm after, _"A part or proportion; a fraction"_.

Comment: To be fair, the _quotum / quota_ singular / plural pairing is given by at least one dictionary, which is confusing. [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quota) gives the almost invariably used _quota / quotas_ pairing, which Collins and R H K Webster's support (though they do not bother to mention the regular plural _quotas_).

Comment: To explain further, it's not clear to me whether "quotum" would perhaps refer to a single unit of quota and not a complete allocation. e.g. a single minute if the allocated quota is time, or a square meter if the allocation is space.

Comment: OK, fair enough. *Quota* (fem) is short for *quota pars* (how great a part), *quotus* (masc.). I haven't seem quotum anywhere. The accepted plural is *quotas*. There is no word like "quot" as a subset for "quota". That would be units you're counting, I would think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) confirms the derivation that appears in medica's second comment above:

> **quota** *n* [ML, fr. L *quota pars*, how great a part] (1618)

The Eleventh Collegiate's entry for *quota* doesn't include a plural form of the word, but that indicates that the plural form is simply *quotas*, because Merriam-Webster's typically includes a word's plural form only when that form varies from the standard English form of *-s* (as in the entries for *quality* ["*n, pl* **-ties**"], *quantum* ["*n, pl* **quanta**"], and *sheep* ["*n, pl* **sheep**"]) or when multiple plural forms are in fairly common use (as in the entries for *agendum* ["*n, pl* **-da** *or* **-dums**"] and *zero* ["*n, pl* **zeros** *also* **zeroes**"]) or when the plural might be mistakenly rendered as *-es* instead of *-s* (as in the entry for solo ["*n, pl* **solos**"]).

Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage* (2003) offers this useful general advice on how to deal with plurals of "borrowed words":

> Words imported into the English language from other languages—especially Greek, Latin, French, and Italian—present some of the most troublesome aspects of English plurals. Many imported words become thoroughly naturalized; if so, they take an English plural. But if a word of Latin or Greek origin is relatively rare in English—or if the foreign plural became established in English long ago—then it typically takes its foreign plural.
>
> One reliable guide is this: if in doubt, use the native-English plural ending in *-s*. That way you'll avoid the mistakes involved in hypercorrection, which is rampant with false foreign plurals (as when people say or write *ignorami* instead of *ignoramuses*, thereby betraying something quite ironic). ... Many writers who try to be sophisticated in their use of language make mistakes such as *ignorami* and *octopi*—unaware that neither is a Latin noun that, when inflected as a plural, becomes *-i*. The proper plural of the Greek word *octopus* is *octopodes*; the proper English plural is *octopuses*.

Garner acknowledges the existence of various exceptions (such as *crises*, *criteria*, and *phenomena*) and "extremely close calls" (such as *cactuses/cacti* and *millenniums/millennia*). But in the long run, he argues, a grandiose notion of fidelity to the Latin or Greek sources of English borrowed words may serve writers ill:

> It's pedantic and prissy to say that politicians attend *fora*, enter *auditoria*, ascend *rostra*, and speak in favor of *referenda*.